# How to resolve "Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DocumentSnapshot>' in type cast"?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using flutter with firestore, and want to fetch data.

Here is my collection.
[Firestore document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdBC2.png)

and my code is:

```
  @override
  Stream<List<Notification>> publicNotifications() {
    return publicNotificationCollection
        .document('cEBC37lg7MtrRNCVcGFw')
        .snapshots()
        .asyncMap((snapshot) {
      List<Notification> notificationList;
      final notifications =
          snapshot.data['notifications'] as List<DocumentSnapshot>;
      for (final notification in notifications) {
        notificationList.add(Notification.fromEntity(
            NotificationEntity.fromSnapshot(notification)));
      }
      return notificationList;
    });
  }
```

Then I got error:

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DocumentSnapshot>' in type cast
```

How to resolve this error?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you casting `List<DocumentSnapShot>` on `snapshot.data['notifications']`? The `snapshot` itself is a `DocumentSnapshot` and not the List inside `data['notifications']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error itself is coming form `as` operator. According to [Dart documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#operators) :

> Use the as operator to cast an object to a particular type if and only if you are sure that the object is of that type.

Guessing from your screenshot `notification` is document field of nested map types, and I don't think its possible to cast it to `List<DocumentSnapshot>`. That's why you get error.

I don't have full picture of your whole project, but maybe you have to figure out how to change it without casting to your desired `Notifiaction` object.
Other option I see, but I don't know how far you can change firestore structure, is to change notification into subcollection, than I think you will be able to query object similar to `List<DocumentSnapshot>`.

I hope this will help!